# How to default export a named import in one line?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

`index.js`

```
import { Human } from 'test';

export default Human;
```

I am importing a named export `Human` from `test`. I am exporting Human as `default` from `index.js` to allow others to import Human from `index.js` instead of `test`.

Ex:

```
import Human from 'index';
```

How to combine the above 2 statements from `index.js` into one line?

Comment: Is `export { Human as default } from 'test'` a thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `as`:

```
export { Human as default } from "test";
```

This imports `Human`, changes it to `default`, and exports it.